# Automatic way to classify if a time series has a peak in a particular month/qtr of the year

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I have around 20 Million time series(say of product demands or merchant's activity for a few past years). I am looking to develop:

1. An automated way to classify these time series as being regular or seasonal(Seasonal here means there is peak activity in some part of the year say every April or even April-May-Jun).
2. For those who are seasonal, I am also looking to tag them with the exact months of their peak activity.

Currently I am exploring a time series clustering based approach on a sample with hope that they will be clustered as per their seasonal patterns. And then build a classifier to classify the remaining into different seasonal time series.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

- Ensure that the time series are stationary (detrend, denoise, remove outliers).
- Use a spectral decomposition method (such as FFT) to decompose each time series into the most important frequencies.
- Perform some discretisation of the observed signals (quarterly cycles with peak in January etc).
- Cluster time series based on presence of matching discretised signals.